# EF Core N+1 Problem while getting 1-N data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

We have 2 tables called Blogs and Comments. Blogs have N Comments. We have a method that takes a list of Blogs' Ids as a parameter. This method should return some basic information about the blogs and their comments. The method is defined as following;

```
public List<BlogDto> GetAllBlogs(List<long> blogIds)
{
    var query = from blogId in blogIds
                join blog in dbContext.Blogs.Include(blog => blog.Comments) on blogId equals blog.Id
                select new BlogDto()
                {
                    Id = blog.Id,
                    Name = blog.Name,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    // Comments prop is List<CommentDto>
                    Comments = blog.Comments.Select(comment => new CommentDto
                                                               {
                                                                   Id = comment.Id,
                                                                   Content = comment.Content 
                                                               }).ToList()

                }

     return query.ToList();
}
```

My question is here why EF Core turns this into N+1 queries even though I have included Comments.

EF  Core Version  : 2.x.

.NET Version      : 4.7.x

We are using WCF service so we could not upgrade .NET version and EF version.

Well, this is the final version of my method;

```
public List<BlogDto> GetAllBlogs(List<long> blogIds)
    {
        var blogQuery = from blogId in blogIds
                        join blog in dbContext.Blogs on blogId equals blog.Id
                        select new BlogDto()
                        {
                            Id = blog.Id,
                            Name = blog.Name,
                            .
                            .
                            .
                        };

        var comments = (from blog in blogQuery
                        join comment in dbContext.Comments on blog.Id equals comment.BlogId
                        select new CommentDto
                        {
                            Id = comment.Id,
                            Content = comment.Content,
                            BlogId = blog.Id
                        }).GropuBy(c => c.BlogId).ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v => v.ToList());

        var blogList = blogQuery.ToList();
        blogList.Foreach(b =>
        {
            if (comments.ContainsKey(b.Id))
            {
                b.Comments = comments[b.Id]
            }
        });

        return blogList;
    }
```

I know it is not very efficient but at least it is working.

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: EF Core 2 is *very* old and used various hacks to cover up for missing functionality. One of these is client-side evaluation. If EF can't generate a SQL query it will load what it can on the client and finish processing in-memory. This should produce runtime warnings though. EF Core 3 and later will throw if they can't generate a single SQL query

Comment: You should consider moving to EF Core 3.1, which is the last version to support .NET Framework. As for `so we could not upgrade .NET version and EF version.` you can use [CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF) to migrate

Comment: @RobertHarvey it generates a select query for every parent entity.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it would be very painful because it is a very big project and this is the only part we have to use nested queries. I would be great if there is a simpler workaround.

Comment: @abdismoz you'll have to do *something* long term. Right now you're mixing .NET Framework with an old .NET Core ORM. Either move everything to .NET (Core) 6 or use [Entity Framework 6.4.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework), the last EF version built for .NET Framework. In fact, EF 6.4.4 is *newer* than EF Core 2

Comment: @abdismoz what do the `Blog` and `Comment` classes look like? How different are they from the DTOs? If they're similar, you could load the entities in memory and *then* map them to DTOs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the entities are much bigger than dtos and there are lots of them so fetching all of them would fill memory.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so you are telling me, there is no way to solve n+1 problem with our current libs?

Comment: Only workarounds. In fact, [N+1 is mentioned in the EF Core 2.1 Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries). The proposed solution is to call `ToList()` in the related query.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its because you started with a join.  You don't need a join for this query.  My EF is a little rusty, but change your query to be something like this:

```
var query = for blog in dbContext.Blogs.Include(blog => blog.Comments)
            where blogIds.Contains(blogId)
            select new BlogDto()
            {
                Id = blog.Id,
                Name = blog.Name,
                .
                .
                .
                // Comments prop is List<CommentDto>
                Comments = blog.Comments.Select(comment => new CommentDto
                                                           {
                                                               Id = comment.Id,
                                                               Content = comment.Content 
                                                           }

            }
```

Comment: The JOIN shouldn't be  a problem ... but. EF Core 2 is *very* old and used various hacks to cover up missing functionality though, including client-side evaluation

Comment: `Include(blog => blog.Comments)` is actually not needed too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is a join with local collection, AFAIK EF Core does not handle those very well (especially older versions), co actually it can be a problem.

Comment: I tried without first join too but the result is the same. EF core executes a select query for every parent entity. Besides that if I use contains it throws "ef core an expression services limit has been reached" when id list is very long. Tried without `Include(blog => blog.Comments)` but that made no difference.

Comment: @abdismoz `Include` forces eager loading of related entities that aren't used in the `Select` clause. It's not needed in this case. This doesn't affect the N+1 problem. That's just how EF Core 2 behaved

Answer (score 0):

As weird as it sounds, just for EF Core 2.1, you need to add `ToList()` in the subquery:

```
    var query = from blog in dbContext.Blogs
                where blogIds.Contains(blog.Id)
                select new BlogDto()
                {
                    Id = blog.Id,
                    Name = blog.Name,
                    Comments = blog.Comments.Select(comment => new CommentDto 
                               {
                                   Id = comment.Id,
                                   Content = comment.Content 
                               }).ToList()
                }
```

This was [a known problem of EF Core 2.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries). EF Core 1 and 2 lacked a *lot* of functionality. The missing features were covered up either by using client-side evaluation or executing multiple queries. EF Core 2.1 was the first that could handle `GroupBy` and mitigate the N+1 problem

The [Optimization of correlated subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries) section explains that to avoid N+1 queries applications need to explicitly call `ToList()` in the correlated subquery.

> The optimization requires buffering the results from the subquery, and we require that you modify the query to opt-in the new behavior.

> As an example, the following query normally gets translated into one query for Customers, plus N (where "N" is the number of customers returned) separate queries for Orders:

```
var query = context.Customers.Select(
    c => c.Orders.Where(o => o.Amount  > 100).Select(o => o.Amount));
```

> By including ToList() in the right place, you indicate that buffering is appropriate for the Orders, which enable the optimization:

```
var query = context.Customers.Select(
    c => c.Orders.Where(o => o.Amount  > 100)
                 .Select(o => o.Amount)
                 .ToList());
```

**Upgrading to .NET 6**

WCF isn't a blocker to migration any more. [CoreWCF](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/) is an open-source port of WCF to .NET Core. Version 1 was released in April 2022. It's not just a recompilation though:

> Usage in code is similar to WCF, but updated to use ASP.NET Core as the service host, and to work with .NET Core. This is the first major release of the project, and provides WCF functionality for .NET Core, .NET Framework, and .NET 5+.

> The 1.0 release of CoreWCF is compatible with .NET Standard 2.0 so that it will work with:

- .NET Framework 4.6.2 (and above)
- .NET Core 3.1
- .NET 5 & 6

Comment: Sorry, actually I forgot to add `ToList()` to my post. I am already calling `ToList()` at child queries but still the problem occurs.

Comment: In that case there are uglier workarounds [like these](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/n1-queries-problem-in-2-0/). One option is to actually write the JOIN in LINQ. The other is to load the related entities (CommentDTOs) and then combine them with BlogDTOs. In both cases you have to do manually what EF Core 3+ would do automatically

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will try combining manually. If that leads any performance issues, I think we should consider upgrading to EF Core 3.